# in place partition does not work for duplicate elements

Tags: python, algorithm, quicksort, data-partitioning

I was trying to implement the in place partition subroutine of quicksort.It works with array of unique elements,but fails when the array contains duplicate elements

The code goes like this

```
def inplace_partitioning(input,l,r):
    len_a=len(input)
    pivot=input[l]
    i=l+1
    for j in range(l+1,r+1,1):
        if input[j]<pivot:#do nothing if new elem >pivot
            #swap new elem with leftmost elem greater than pivot
            temp=input[j]
            input[j]=input[i]
            input[i]=temp
            i+=1
    #swap pivot with rightmost elem lessthan pivot
    temp=input[l]
    input[l]=input[i-1]
    input[i-1]=temp
```

When the input is of unique elements,the code gives correct results

```
input=[5,6,3,1,8,4]
inplace_partitioning(input,0,len(input)-1)
print input

>>[4, 3, 1, 5, 8, 6]
```

when I tried the array below,i got wrong results

```
input=[5,6,3,1,8,5]
>>>[1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 5]
```

Is this because my implementation faulty?can someone help out  a bit?

Comment: What happened when you debugged this?

Comment: Note that in Python, you can swap values with `a, b = b, a`

Comment: Also, in what way is that second example wrong?

Comment: the number 5 should be on the left side of pivot

Comment: @damon: Where is the logic in your code that enforces that?

Comment: I see,the input[j]<pivot check is not enough to handle a duplicate..

Comment: @damon: Yup.  But you would have spotted that if you had stepped through your code in the debugger...

Comment: @Oli,my fault..sorry and thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
if input[j]<pivot:
```

This means it will only move numbers left of the pivot if they are smaller.
However you want numbers equal to the size of the pivot to be moved, otherwise numbers of equal size to the pivot will be spread throughout the right of the pivot.

change it to:

```
if input[j]<=pivot:
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get your algorithm, and it doesn't look like quicksort partitioning. Normally, you run i and j in different directions, one starting at the top of the interval and one at the bottom, but if I understand correctly, yours run in the same direction. In the first iteration, i and j have the same value, and if it is smaller than the pivot, it is exchanged for itself (i.e. the same effect as if it is NOT smaller than the pivot)?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
def partitionv(arr, l, r):

    p = r
    idx = l
    for i in range(l, r-1, 1):
        if arr[i] < arr[p]:
            arr[i], arr[idx] = arr[idx], arr[i]
            idx += 1
    arr[p], arr[idx] = arr[idx], arr[p]

    return arr
```

this is a partition of the element on the right.